# How to write lowpass filter for sampled signal in Python?

Tags: python, filter, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

I am new in signal processing, and I didn't find Python code with good explanation. So I will be glad to get a simple explanation.

I have some signal that sampled each 1 nsec (1e-9 sec) and have, let say, 1e4 points. I need to filter high frequencies from this signal. Let say I need to filter frequencies higher than 10MHz. I want that for frequencies lower than cutoff frequency signal will be passed unchanged. It means gain of the filter will be 1 for frequencies lower than cutoff frequency.

I would like to be able to specify filter order. I mean, first order filter have 20 db/decade slope (power rolloff) after cutoff frequency, second order filter have 40 db/dec slope after cutoff frequency and so on. High performance of code is important.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I tryed this one http://azitech.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/designing-a-butterworth-low-pass-filter-with-scipy/

Answer (score 9):

You appear to have two questions:

1. How do I design a lowpass filter with a 10MHz cutoff frequency and an arbitrary filter order?
2. How do I realise that filter in Python?

Filter design is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow - that's a DSP problem, not a programming problem. Filter design is covered by any DSP textbook - go to your library. I like Proakis and Manolakis' *Digital Signal Processing*. (Ifeachor and Jervis' *Digital Signal Processing* isn't bad either.)

If you must have teh coeds, try [this blog post](https://azitech.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/designing-a-butterworth-low-pass-filter-with-scipy/), which shows how to design a Butterworth lowpass filter with `scipy`.

As for implementation of the filter in Python, `scipy` has a [`lfilter()` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) which applies a FIR or IIR filter to a signal in one dimension.

Comment: See also http://dsp.stackexchange.com for the DSP/filter design part of the question.