# Filtering a wav file using python

Tags: python, audio, filtering, wav

So i recently successfully built a system which will record, plot, and playback an audio wav file entirely with python. Now, I'm trying to put some filtering and audio mixing in between the when i record and when i start plotting and outputting the file to the speakers. However, i have no idea where to start. Right now I'm to read in a the intial wav file, apply a low pass filter, and then re-pack the newly filtered data into a new wav file. Here is the code i used to plot the initial data once i recorded it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wave
import sys

spf = wave.open('wavfile.wav','r')

#Extract Raw Audio from Wav File
signal = spf.readframes(-1)
signal = np.fromstring(signal, 'Int16')

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Signal Wave...')
plt.plot(signal)
```

And here is some code i used to generate a test audio file of a single tone:

```
import numpy as np
import wave
import struct

freq = 440.0
data_size = 40000
fname = "High_A.wav"
frate = 11025.0  
amp = 64000.0    

sine_list_x = []
for x in range(data_size):
    sine_list_x.append(np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*(x/frate)))

wav_file = wave.open(fname, "w")

nchannels = 1
sampwidth = 2
framerate = int(frate)
nframes = data_size
comptype = "NONE"
compname = "not compressed"

wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes,
comptype, compname))

for s in sine_list_x:
    wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int(s*amp/2)))

wav_file.close()
```

I'm not really sure how to apply said audio filter and repack it, though. Any help and/or advice you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `scipy`'s [lfilter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html)?

Comment: Rather than the for loop to generate the sinusoid, you want something like `sine_signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*(np.arange(data_size)/frate))`, then something like `wav_file.writeframes((sine_signal*amp/2).astype('h').tostring())`.

Answer (score 58):

### First step : What kind of audio filter do you need ?

#### Choose the filtered band

- [Low-pass Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) : remove highest frequency from your audio signal
- [High-pass Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter) : remove lowest frequencies from your audio signal
- [Band-pass Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-pass_filter) : remove both highest and lowest frequencies from your audio signal

For the following steps, i assume you need a **Low-pass Filter**.

#### Choose your cutoff frequency

The [Cutoff frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency) is the frequency where your signal will be attenuated by -3dB.

Your example signal is 440Hz, so let's choose a [Cutoff frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency) of **400Hz**. Then your 440Hz-signal is attenuated (more than -3dB), by the Low-pass 400Hz filter.

#### Choose your filter type

According to [this other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428426/how-to-write-lowpass-filter-for-sampled-signal-in-python)

> Filter design is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow - that's a DSP
>   problem, not a programming problem. Filter design is covered by any
>   DSP textbook - go to your library. I like Proakis and Manolakis'
>   Digital Signal Processing. (Ifeachor and Jervis' Digital Signal
>   Processing isn't bad either.)

To go inside a simple example, I suggest to use a **moving average** filter (for a simple low-pass filter).

See [Moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)

> Mathematically, a moving average is a type of convolution and so it can be viewed as an example of a low-pass filter used in signal processing

This Moving average Low-pass Filter is a basic filter, and it is quite easy to use and to understand.

The parameter of the moving average is the **window length**.

The relationship between [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) window length and [Cutoff frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency) needs little bit mathematics and is explained [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/14648/51023)

The code will be

```py
import math

sampleRate = 11025.0 
cutOffFrequency = 400.0
freqRatio = cutOffFrequency / sampleRate

N = int(math.sqrt(0.196201 + freqRatio**2) / freqRatio)
```

So, in the example, the window length will be **12**

### Second step : coding the filter

#### Hand-made moving average

see [specific discussion on how to create a moving average in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean)

Solution from [Alleo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498892/alleo) is

```
def running_mean(x, windowSize):
   cumsum = numpy.cumsum(numpy.insert(x, 0, 0)) 
   return (cumsum[windowSize:] - cumsum[:-windowSize]) / windowSize 

filtered = running_mean(signal, N)
```

#### Using lfilter

Alternatively, as suggested by [dpwilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3818521/dpwilson), we can also use lfilter

```
win = numpy.ones(N)
win *= 1.0/N
filtered = scipy.signal.lfilter(win, [1], signal).astype(channels.dtype)
```

### Third step : Let's Put It All Together

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import wave
import sys
import math
import contextlib

fname = 'test.wav'
outname = 'filtered.wav'

cutOffFrequency = 400.0

# from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean
def running_mean(x, windowSize):
  cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(x, 0, 0)) 
  return (cumsum[windowSize:] - cumsum[:-windowSize]) / windowSize

# from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226853/interpreting-wav-data/2227174#2227174
def interpret_wav(raw_bytes, n_frames, n_channels, sample_width, interleaved = True):

    if sample_width == 1:
        dtype = np.uint8 # unsigned char
    elif sample_width == 2:
        dtype = np.int16 # signed 2-byte short
    else:
        raise ValueError("Only supports 8 and 16 bit audio formats.")

    channels = np.fromstring(raw_bytes, dtype=dtype)

    if interleaved:
        # channels are interleaved, i.e. sample N of channel M follows sample N of channel M-1 in raw data
        channels.shape = (n_frames, n_channels)
        channels = channels.T
    else:
        # channels are not interleaved. All samples from channel M occur before all samples from channel M-1
        channels.shape = (n_channels, n_frames)

    return channels

with contextlib.closing(wave.open(fname,'rb')) as spf:
    sampleRate = spf.getframerate()
    ampWidth = spf.getsampwidth()
    nChannels = spf.getnchannels()
    nFrames = spf.getnframes()

    # Extract Raw Audio from multi-channel Wav File
    signal = spf.readframes(nFrames*nChannels)
    spf.close()
    channels = interpret_wav(signal, nFrames, nChannels, ampWidth, True)

    # get window size
    # from http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/what-is-the-cut-off-frequency-of-a-moving-average-filter
    freqRatio = (cutOffFrequency/sampleRate)
    N = int(math.sqrt(0.196196 + freqRatio**2)/freqRatio)

    # Use moviung average (only on first channel)
    filtered = running_mean(channels[0], N).astype(channels.dtype)

    wav_file = wave.open(outname, "w")
    wav_file.setparams((1, ampWidth, sampleRate, nFrames, spf.getcomptype(), spf.getcompname()))
    wav_file.writeframes(filtered.tobytes('C'))
    wav_file.close()
```

Comment: Hi, I think your code has accidentally become a high-pass filter. I used it on a wav audio and ended up removing the bass. I need both low and high pass filters, so could you point me to the part that needs to be changed?

Comment: I confirm it is working as a low pass on my end.
Can you share the wav file you are using ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is working as an LPF. Apparently the bass was a higher frequency than the foreground.

Comment: What is the meaning of `[1]` in `win, [1], signal`?

Comment: @user13107 Doesn't GitHub's terms conflict with Stack Overflow's license?

Comment: @BSMP I tried to search for Meta question where this issue (`copying code from github to SO`) is handled; but I couldnt find it. Note that the github code is also written by OP. Can we just mention that this code is taken from GitHub and same license is applicable here?

Comment: @user13107 see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html#scipy-signal-lfilter in `nfilter`, we use a more generic concept of  IIR or FIR filter. 

This is a polynomial defined-filter per the equation `a[0]*y[n] = b[0]*x[n] + b[1]*x[n-1] + ... + b[M]*x[n-M] - a[1]*y[n-1] - ... - a[N]*y[n-N]`

We use `b = win, a = [1], x = signal` 

then equation is `1*y[n] = win[0]*signal[n] + win[1]*signal[n-1] + ... + win[M]*signal[n-M]`

It's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut but it works !

Comment: I use this to filter certain instruments from wav-files and it works like a charm. Only thing: it gives me a depraction warning: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead
  channels = np.fromstring(raw_bytes, dtype=dtype). Anyone knows how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

`sox library` can be used for static noise removal.

I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/devoncrouse/5534261) which has some useful commands as examples