# Python filtering audio

Tags: python, audio, filter

So I'm trying to write a program that filters certain frequencies from audio in real time. I found out about band filters and I was wondering if I can use this to get a certain range of 60-250hz or if I need to do something else to get this range.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question about filtering audio with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920346/filtering-a-wav-file-using-python) already?

Comment: No I din't find this in my google search. Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem! Want me to add that as an answer for this?

Comment: Yeah I can I'm not sure how to do that off a comment though

Comment: Ahhh fair. I've never worked with this library so I figured I'd chime in with resources, but I can't help much beyond that.